# How can I paginate docker logs commands in linux?

Tags: linux, docker, terminal, less

I am not able to paginate `docker logs` commands with `less`.

`docker logs <CONTAINER> | less` jumps right to the end. I have to `&>` to a temp file and paginate there.

Why is that? How is it possible to paginate?

I searched extensively and tried `less -R`, `less -S` and other suggestions but nothing worked.

Comment: `jumps right to the end` So scroll up. I do not understand. I can't reproduce.

Comment: I don't want to scroll back, I want to paginate forward. Page by page, as `less` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`some_command | less` only sends stdout to the less command, and everything printed to stderr will be displayed outside of less.

To merge stderr into stdout, you can use the syntax:

```bash
some_command 2>&1 | less
```

Comment: holy @#$% not sure how it did not occur to me to try this. Works perfectly. Thanks.